# TreePlot: arrows on specific lines

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, options

I have the following list of rules:

```
L={1->2,2->3,3->3};
```

and I want to plot a tree graph:

```
TreePlot[L,VertexRenderingFunction->({Disk[#,.02],Text[#2,#1+{.15,0}]}&)]
```

[image: tree_graph]

The thing is, I would like to have the arrows only on certain lines, such as the second one, `2->3`. To this end, I shall write the rules as

```
L={{1->2,2->3,3->3},{False,True,False}};
```

and generate the tree by `TreePlot[L[[1]],...]`. My question is: how can I get the arrows only at `True` positions, as in the example above?

I thought I could use directed edges and undirected edges, that is,

```
L={UndirectedEdge[1,2],DirectedEdge[2,3],UndirectedEdge[3,3]};
```

but i get the message `TreePlot::grph:L is not a valid graph.`

How can I make it work?

Comment: Don't use the outdated `TreePlot`.  Use `Graph` instead with `GraphLayout`

Comment: How can I specify the root node in Graph? The third slot in TreePlot is the root node, but in Graph there is no mention (in the documentation) of the root node (I think).

Comment: When I wrote the comment, I didn't realize that it's not going to go as smoothly as it should ... I wrote a more detailed answer.  The graph layouts are documented in the `GraphLayout` doc page.  There's *a lot* of information squeezed in there about lots and lots of different layout methods, their suboptions, etc.  It's a bit confusion as usually this amount of stuff wouldn't be hidden behind a single options and its suboptions.  It's too easy to miss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TreePlot` is the old way to plot trees. It has been superseded by `Graph` and `GraphLayout`.  `GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding"` can be used for trees.  Please check the documentation on how to set various options for this embedding, including specifying the root: [`GraphLayout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphLayout.html). They're a bit hidden down the page.

Mathematica 10 and later supports mixed graphs with both directed and undirected edges.  One way to accomplish what you want is to use these.  Unfortunately `"LayeredGraphEmbedding"` doesn't seem to support them.  As a workaround we create an undirected graph, compute the vertex coordinates, then apply them to our mixed graph.

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 <-> 3}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
UndirectedGraph[g, 
   GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
pts = GraphEmbedding[%];

SetProperty[g, VertexCoordinates -> pts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, this last step could be replaces by custom code that takes `pts`, the edge list, some directedness specification for the edges, and draws the edges manually, putting the arrowheads where necessary.

Comment: That was really helpful, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use `TreePlot`, you can also

**Use `EdgeRenderingFunction`:**

```
TreePlot[L, VertexRenderingFunction -> ({Disk[#, .02], Text[#2, #1 + {.05, .025}]} &), 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Darker@Red, 
     If[#2 === {2, 3}, {Arrowheads[{0, 0, .05, 0}], Arrow[#]}, Line[#]]} &)]
```

[image]

**Post-process selected `Line`s to `Arrow`s:**

```
TreePlot[L, VertexRenderingFunction -> ({Disk[#, .02], Text[#2, #1 + {.05, .025}]} &)] /. 
 Line[x_] :> (Line /@ x ) /. 
 Line[{2, 3}] :> {Arrowheads[{0, 0, .05, 0}], Arrow[{2, 3}]}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I was already using `VertexRenderingFunction`, but it didn't occur to me that one can also use `EdgeRenderingFunction` for a similar purpose (but to modify edges instead of vertices). Thank you very much!